# CSS/SASS: Parent declaration in SASS

Tags: css, sass

What does this look like in SASS? I don't understand what it would look like.

```
.icon-button .up-arrow, 
.icon-button .down-arrow {
    background-image: url('/images/icons/sprites.png');
} 

.icon-button .down-arrow {
    background-position:20px 0;
}

.icon-button .up-arrow {
    background-position:40px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
.icon-button {
    .down-arrow, .up-arrow {
        background-image: url('/images/icons/sprites.png');
    }

    .down-arrow {
        background-position:20px 0;
    }

    .up-arrow {
        background-position:40px 0;
    }
}
```

Amongst many other things, SASS allows you to add nested rules.

This is probably overkill in your case but you can also parameterize some of the values.  Just for demo purposes:

```
$first: 20px;
$second: 40px;

.icon-button {
    .down-arrow, .up-arrow {
        background-image: url('/images/icons/sprites.png');
    }

    .down-arrow {
        background-position: $first 0;
    }

    .up-arrow {
        background-position: $second 0;
    }
}
```

If you really want to go nuts with it, you can create reusable functions (or "mixins" in SASS lingo):

```
@mixin calcBackground($padding) {
    background-position: ($padding + 20px) 0;
}

.icon-button {
    .down-arrow, .up-arrow {
        background-image: url('/images/icons/sprites.png');
    }
    .down-arrow {
        @include calcBackground(0px);
    }

    .up-arrow {
        @include calcBackground(20px);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nit-picking, but for clarity I will point out that your example here doesn't mean the same thing as the OP's CSS. If there was another element like `<span class=".icon-button .side-arrow">` it would share the same background image as ".up-arrow" and ".down-arrow". In the OP's case, this is probably ok since it is a sprite image, but in others that might not be.

Comment: @jessegavin ok...edited. thanks for pointing it out to me =)  i appreciate you being nit-picky.  it's good to know at least someone is reading this post =)

Comment: being even more nit-picky, you could clean up the code even more by putting `.down-arrow, .up-arrow { background-image: url(); } .down-arrow { background-position: # #; } .up-arrow { background-position: # #; }` since they both use the same sprite.

Comment: @Patrick Robert Shea O'Connor good point!  edited the code to reflect your suggestion.  definitely easier to maintain and eliminates some redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out as well.

```
.icon-button{
  &.up-arrow{
    background-image: url('/images/icons/sprites.png');
    background-position:40px 0;
  }
  &.down-arrow{
    background-image: url('/images/icons/sprites.png');
    background-position:20px 0;
  }
}
```

I hope it helps. Thank you